# Resultset (getter/setter class) object not deleting old values at 2nd Time execution

Tags: java, swing, resultset

I have summarizeData() method and called so many time for value retrieve. but first time is working file but 2nd time execution value is increasing in HashMap.

```
    void summarizeData() {

    HashMap outerMap = new HashMap();

    ArrayList list = new ArrayList(dataClass.getData());


    for (int indx = 0; indx < list.size(); indx++) {
        System.out.println("indx : " + indx);
        Resultset rs = new Resultset();
        rs = (Resultset) list.get(indx);


        if (rs != null) {

            int id = rs.getTestCaseNumber();
            if (id > 0) {
                Object isExists = outerMap.get(id);

                if (isExists != null) {
                    //System.out.println("found entry so updating");
                    Resultset inRs = new Resultset();
                    inRs = (Resultset) isExists;

                    if (inRs != null) {
                        int totExec = inRs.getTestExecution();
                        int totPass = inRs.getTestCasePass();
                        int totFail = inRs.getTestCaseFail();

                        //     System.out.println("totE :" + totExec + "  totP:" + totPass + "  totF:" + totFail);

                        int newRsStat = rs.getTestCasePass();

                        if (newRsStat == 1) {
                            totPass++;
                            inRs.setTestCasePass(totPass);
                        } else {
                            totFail++;
                            inRs.setTestCaseFail(totFail);
                        }
                        totExec++;

                        //      System.out.println("id : "+id+"  totPass: "+totPass+"  totFail:"+totFail);
                        //       System.out.println("key : " + id + "  val : " + inRs.getTestCaseNumber() + " " + inRs.getTestCasePass() + "  " + inRs.getTestCaseFail());

                        inRs.setTestExecution(totExec);
                        outerMap.put(id, inRs);
                    }

                } else {

                    //    System.out.println("not exist so new entry" + " totE:" + rs.getTestExecution() + "  totP:" + rs.getTestCasePass() + "  totF:" + rs.getTestCaseFail());
                    outerMap.put(id, rs);
                }
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("rs null");
        }


    }
```

Output at 1st Execution:

```
indx : 0
indx : 1
indx : 2
indx : 3
indx : 4
indx : 5
indx : 6
indx : 7
indx : 8
indx : 9
indx : 10
totE :1  totP:1  totF:0
indx : 11
totE :1  totP:1  totF:0
indx : 12
totE :1  totP:1  totF:0
indx : 13
totE :1  totP:1  totF:0
indx : 14
totE :1  totP:1  totF:0
indx : 15
totE :1  totP:1  totF:0
indx : 16
totE :1  totP:1  totF:0
indx : 17
totE :1  totP:1  totF:0
indx : 18
totE :1  totP:1  totF:0
indx : 19
totE :1  totP:1  totF:0
```

Output at 2nd Execution:

```
indx : 0
indx : 1
indx : 2
indx : 3
indx : 4
indx : 5
indx : 6
indx : 7
indx : 8
indx : 9
indx : 10
totE :2  totP:2  totF:0
indx : 11
totE :2  totP:2  totF:0
indx : 12
totE :2  totP:2  totF:0
indx : 13
totE :2  totP:2  totF:0
indx : 14
totE :2  totP:2  totF:0
indx : 15
totE :2  totP:2  totF:0
indx : 16
totE :2  totP:2  totF:0
indx : 17
totE :2  totP:2  totF:0
indx : 18
totE :2  totP:2  totF:0
indx : 19
totE :2  totP:2  totF:0
```

while i required same output on every execution.

Comment: I did'nt see any difference in o/p

Comment: both output are different ... you may see on above console

Comment: What does the getTestExecution() method do?

Comment: public class Resultset implements Comparable {

    
    private int testCaseNumber = 0;
    private int testExecution = 0;
    private int testCasePass = 0;
    private int testCaseFail = 0;
    private String testResult = "";
    private String testCaseDateTime = "";
    // getter and setter created }

Comment: getTestExecution() method is only get the value from Resultset getter/setter class

Comment: I think the below standing answer solves your question. You're incrementing an value then setting it in the inRs object and afterwards retrieving it from the inRs object. If you remove the `totPass++` and so on (like in the answer below) you'll be fine

Answer (score 2):

Values are incrementing because in following line:

```
totPass++;
inRs.setTestCasePass(totPass);
```

And

```
totFail++;
inRs.setTestCaseFail(totFail);
```

And

```
totExec++;
inRs.setTestExecution(totExec);
```

You are incrementing the `testCasePass` ,`testcaseFail` and `testexecution` value via `inRs` reference variable which is reflected in `isExists` and hence in the element present in the `outerMap`. This is so because all variables (`rs` and `inRs` are sharing the same object i.e. object at `outerMap.get(id)` ). 
That's why each time you are calling the method `summarizeData` you are getting incremented values for the fields.

**UPDATE**
To overcome this problem , You should use copy constructor in `ResultSet` class which look something like this:

```
public ResultSet(ResultSet rs)
{
    testCasePass = rs.getTestCasePass();
    testCaseFail = rs.getTestCaseFail();
    testExecution = rs.getTestExecution();
}
```

And when you create `inRs` , use the following line:

```
ResultSet inRs = new ResultSet(isExists);
```

**UPDATE**

And don't put `inRs` to `outperMap`.

Comment: how to get solution over this problem against rs and inRs are sharing the same object i.e. object at list.get(index)

Comment: same problem occurring ... I'm getting ... 2 constructor made 1st constructor is your given. second one is public Resultset(){}

Comment: @user2384525 why are you incrementing the values? What do you actually want to do in this program?

Comment: If, i will put put inRs to outperMap how can i print the number in table

Comment: @user2384525: I am glad that it solved your problem.. Don't forget to mark the answer as accepted...